# Remove dead code with uglifyjs-webpack-plugin, if const import from another module

Tags: javascript, webpack, uglifyjs

Configuration:

```
"webpack": "4.15.1"
"uglifyjs-webpack-plugin": "1.2.7"
```

Situation:

utils/themes.js

```
const isA = false;
export default {isA};
```

main.js

```
import { isA } from 'utils/themes';
if (isA) {
  console.warn(1);
}
```

After webpack compiling and minimizing, line with `console` isn't deleted.
Is it possible that uglifyjs + webpack detect true/false const in modules and remove dead code?

Comment: For that, you have to use [prepack](https://prepack.io/)